# How did Donatien convince the servants to kill for him?

Tags: la-revolution

In the French series *La Révolution*, Donatien invites a number of relatively minor nobles to his chateau, where he has a number of servants grab them from behind and strangle them, one for each noble.

It would seem difficult to convince a single servant—not even soldiers, but seemingly footmen or butlers of some sort—to kill a noble, let alone more than a dozen, while exhibiting obvious signs of mental instability,<sup>1</sup> to prevail upon some dozen or more to do so in full view of each other, bearing in mind that killing a noble might be considered high treason and could lead to their executions if discovered.<sup>2</sup> Though as count, Donatien would have some authority over lesser nobles, that authority would certainly not extend to arbitrary executions with no trial whatsoever. Moreover, the servants remained unperturbed afterward when Donatien and his friends engaged in strange actions such as taking out syringes full of blue liquid, suggesting that they were aware of his plans or simply unconcerned with what they might be.

How did Donatien convince these servants to kill all the nobles? Were they even servants, or mercenaries of some sort that he had hired?

<sup><sub>1: Apart from his mannerisms, his father was left lying dead in the hall, showing obvious signs of a brutally violent death, for who knows how long, with his son showing no concern about his death whatsoever.</sub></sup>

<sup><sub>2: Of course, the king probably would not care, since he is implied to be behind the events, and the nobles would not stay dead, but from the perspective of the servants, they would have just guaranteed themselves a painful execution (most likely) or penury (at best) when the disappearance of a dozen-odd nobles at their count’s estate becomes known.</sub></sup>

Comment: People with plenty of money rarely struggle to find [hired goons](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilMinions), either in fiction or in real life

Comment: @Valorum - OK, but it's one thing to hire mercenaries and another thing to convince a dozen random servants to do it. Were the servants actually mercenaries?